# React: Safari didn't throw error when I call an array function on an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, safari

While setting state in a React component, I tried:

```
this.setState((pState) => {return {contact: this.state.concat([contact])}; }).
```

I figured this.state was an object while `.concat` was an array method, so Chrome threw an error. But curiously, Safari didn't throw an error. Why is this happening? Could anyone point the direction at which I should look?

Comment: weird. wouldnt spend too much time on something that is obviously an error anyway.

Comment: "*I figured this.state was an object…*" Arrays are objects too. ;-)

Comment: Can't reproduce I get for Safari 11 `TypeError: concat is not a function.`